# Handling dispose method when using hot restart

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to properly dispose resources when using hot restart:

> Hot restart loads code changes into the VM, and restarts the Flutter app, losing the app state. (⇧⌘\ in IntelliJ and Android Studio, ⇧⌘F5 in VSCode)

In my app, I have a heavy resource (here a audio player) which is created on `initState` then disposed in `dispose`.

When tapping the button, it will start playing a song:

```dart
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: const MyHomePage()));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late AudioPlayer audioPlayer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("Creating audio player");
    audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("Disposing audio player");
    audioPlayer.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          print("Starting new song");
          final result = await audioPlayer.play(
            'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c2/Toccata_and_Fugue_in_D_Minor_%28ISRC_USUAN1100350%29.mp3',
          );
          await audioPlayer.resume();
          print(result);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The issue is when hot restart is used, the `dispose` method is not called, so the song playing before the hot restart does not stop and tapping the button will start playing another song over the top of the last song.

What is the correct way to dispose an object when hot restart is used given `dispose` is not called?

My pubspec is the default pubspec with `audioplayers` dependency added:

```yaml
name: flutter_application_1
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.0-10.0.dev <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  audioplayers: ^0.20.1
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: It depends, sometimes I need to hot restart which causes this overlapping sound problem

Comment: What does this have to do with disposing an object? Like if you're using android, `audioplayers` uses the MediaPlayer API which exists outside of your flutter app. Flutter does not know that it needs to call release on the MediaPlayer; you have to do it yourself. Even if hot restart did call dispose, it wouldn't solve your problem because disposing the audioplayer object does not release the MediaPlayer. Since this is a development issue, just add a button that releases or stops the player and press it before hot restart

Comment: Calling `dispose` on the audio player releases its resources and also stops playing music. With hot reload you can use the `recreate` method, but this question is how to free the resources when using hot restart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no simple way to fix this.

Hot-restarting your app is basically like killing it's process and starting it again (with updated code), but witout actual native process being killed. This implies that app being killed because of hot-restart cannot execute any cleanup code (hence no equivalent of `reassemble` method of hot reload).

Unfortunately, platform plugins are not notified of hot-restart (there's an open [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10437) in flutter engine, you can upvote it), so they also cannot cleanup resources acquired by   app being hot-restarted.

One possible workaround would be to release all previously acquired resources on app startup. On first startup nothing would be released, after hot restart app would release resources from the previous run. Unfortunately, `audioplayers` (and other libraries like `flutter_sound`) does not expose any global "disposeAll" API.

So, tl;dr, best solution is the one that @PatrickMahomes provided, add a development-time button to stop the players before hot-restart (or just ignore the problem since it will never come up in a release build). But, if you for some reason would *really* want to do it, here is a

**Ugly and insane hack that I would absolutely not recommend implementing:**

One way to make this work in `audioplayers`, would be to save IDs of plaing players (when they're being started, not when the app is being killed) to some persistent storage, read them when app is being started (as described above) and call `AudioPlayer(playerId: id).release()` on every of them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by Hot-Realoading not beeing able to notify the plugin about hot-restart.

**This solution is just a workaround for your specific situation.**

I would save the player ID as soon as you initialise the player:

```
Future<AudioPlayer> _initPlayer() async {
    print("Creating audio player");
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final playerId = prefs.getString('audioPlayer');
    if (playerId != null) {
      AudioPlayer(playerId: playerId).release();
    }
    final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    await prefs.setString('audioPlayer', audioPlayer.playerId);
    return audioPlayer;
  }
```

This function uses `SharedPreferences` to store the `playerId`. Each time you init the player, this code checks for a stored ID, if there is one it creates an `AudioPlayer` with that ID and releases it.
Then it proceeds creating a new one.

Since this function is asynchronous, it cannot be run inside the `initState()`.

I wrapped the `FloatingActionButton` inside a FutureBuilder linked to the `_initPlayer()` function.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initPlayer(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<AudioPlayer> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            audioPlayer = snapshot.data!;
            return FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                print("Starting new song");
                await audioPlayer.play(
                  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c2/Toccata_and_Fugue_in_D_Minor_%28ISRC_USUAN1100350%29.mp3',
                );
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
            );
          }

          return FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => {},
            child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Ah yes, my `Ugly and insane hack that I would absolutely not recommend implementing` but with code :D

Comment: Oh, yes, I've just read your answer. Anyway this hack is only workaround. The problem is due to hot reloading not notifying the plugin.